# Not sure how to Initializing this local variable

Tags: c

**Am a beginner in c**, I cant initialize this 
local variable dotP. When I run the code it gives
me this  error:Error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'dotP' used.
Please tell me the code and where to insert the initialization code.
Any other correction will be appreciated.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <time.h>

 #define N 10
 float AUX;


 typedef struct complex{
double a;
double b;
 }complex;


 double randN(double min, double max){

double range = (max - min);
double div = max / range;
return min + (rand() / div);

  }

void fillVector(complex* v1, complex* v2){
int i = 0;


for (i = 0; i< N; i++){
    v1[i].a = randN(0, 100);
    v1[i].b = randN(0, 100);
    v2[i].a = randN(0, 100);
    v2[i].b = randN(0, 100);
  }
  }


 void calculate(complex* v1, complex* v2){
int i = 0, j = 0;


complex dotP;
complex c1, c2;

for (i = 0; i< N; i++){
    for (j = 0; j <N; j++){
        c1.a = v1[i].a;
        c1.b = v1[i].b;
        c2.a = v2[j].a; c2.b = v2[j].b; 
        // 


        dotP.a += ((c1.a*c2.a) - (c1.b*c2.b)); /* take care of real part */
        dotP.b += ((c1.a*c2.b) + (c1.b*c2.a)); /*take care of imaginary */
       }
   }
     }


    int main()
      {

clock_t begin, end;
double time_spent;


complex* v1 = (complex *)malloc(sizeof(complex)*N);
complex* v2 = (complex *)malloc(sizeof(complex)*N);

begin = clock(); /* init clock */
calculate(v1, v2); /*consume time */
end = clock();  /*stop clock */
time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("Elapsed: %f seconds\n", (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);/*showdata*/

return 0;
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Either:

```
complex dotP;
...
dotP.a = 0.0;
dotP.b = 0.0;
```

Or

```
complex dotP = {0.0, 0.0};
```

Comment: This site is a place to be be as a beginner and gurus in programming.Please keep it us. Very soon I will join you guys in solving peoples problems too.